# Unable to create view due to same column names (and modifying column name isn't an option)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view

I have the following query:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, s.fname, s.lname, e.salary
FROM employee e JOIN
     employee s
     ON s.ssn = e.super_ssn JOIN
     department d 
     ON e.dno = d.dnumber
WHERE d.dname = 'Research'
```

That works peachy for the intention I had. But I wanted to create a `View` of that so that object is fetched instead of a query having to be run again every time. The problem is that whenever I tried to submit that query with `CREATE VIEW <name>` I get the following error:
`column "fname" specified more than once`.

I'm new to SQL `(Postgres)`, just learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns in a view need to have distinct names.  So, assign new names, such as:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname,
       s.fname as supervisor_fname, s.lname as supervisor_lname,
       e.salary
FROM employee e JOIN
     employee s
     ON s.ssn = e.super_ssn JOIN
     department d 
     ON e.dno = d.dnumber
WHERE d.dname = 'Research'
```

Comment: Thank you! How does this recognize the correct table in this case? I had tried using the `AS` keyword but didn't find anything about this example you gave me during my search.

Comment: @LukePerez . . . I assume the alias `e` is for "employee" and `s` is for "supervisor".

Answer (score 1):

You can use aliases to differentiate the column names:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name as
SELECT e.fname e_fname, e.lname e_lname, s.fname s_fname, s.lname s_lname, e.salary
FROM employee e JOIN
     employee s
     ON s.ssn = e.super_ssn JOIN
     department d 
     ON e.dno = d.dnumber
WHERE d.dname = 'Research'
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help!